# Can't download file from dropbox.com with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I have web application that can download from dropbox.com. The application is written using Javascript. I'm using the `dropbox.min.js` http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-js/ library running on a client. 
This is a function of the library:

```
client.readFile(name, function(error, data) {
   if (error) {
      return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
   }
   saveFile(name, data);
});
```

`saveFile(name, data)` is my function doing the following:

```
var saveFile = function(file, data)
{
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); 
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'saving.php', true); 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    xmlhttp.send("fileName=" + file + "&data=" + data); 

}

function getXmlHttp(){
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

The problem is: while I'm trying to download assets (e.g. jpg doc, gif, etc.), I only receive 1kb instead of the full file. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: The problem (other bugs in your `saveFile` function aside) is that you cannot send binary data to over HTTP using the `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` content type. What type does `data` have? The Google code project you link to looks empty for me, it don't see any source code there.

Comment: There is source code in the svn/trunk directory. (Source -> Browse -> svn -> trunk)

Comment: I'm trying to download jpg, doc, etc. Also I've tried to change content type to image/jpg, but nothing happend.

Comment: Using the image content type is certainly the correct way to do it. How did you send the data? It should work if you send it like this `xmlhttp.send(data);` assuming `data` is the actual image data.

Comment: It's my full code [link](http://pastebin.com/eUBq9kjv) and [link](http://pastebin.com/SCPiKP4B). and it doesn't work if I even write image/jpg

Answer (score 0):

The [official JavaScript library](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) can download binary files in browsers that support XHR level 2 (Chrome, Firefox, IE 10).

See the sample code in the [getting started document](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/doc/getting_started.md), and use the `blob: true` option when calling `readFile`.